# Why there is not dxdy factor in fft2() function of MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, fft, ifft

In analytical 2D Fourier Transform, integrand is multiplied by dxdy.
In algorithm of MATLAB function fft2(), this is not done.

In discrete case, dx is Lx/Nx and dy = Ly/Ny,

where Lx,Ly are lengths in metres and Nx,Ny are number of samples in x,y directions.

```
   https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft2.html
```

Is it not correct to multiply by dxdy after using fft2() for user function i.e. matrix ?

Similarly for ifft2() function in MATLAB, there is no (dk_x)*(dk_y)
where dk_x = 1/Lx    and  dk_y = 1/Ly

```
   https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ifft2.html
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I assume just because when MATLAB does `fft2` it assumes that the `Lx==Ly==(e.g.)1` thus you do not need it to do the maths.

Comment: @AnderBiguri: I did not get what you are saying. Will you please elaborate it ?

Comment: Not sure if there is anything to elaborate: you don't need it. it computes "normalized" fft. `lx=ly=1` (I think)

Comment: The help page you linked described the [mathematical formulation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft2.html#bvhcnas): See also wikipedia's page on [DFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform)